# Core Data code generation causes build failure

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode8

I’m using the new Xcode 8 feature of code generation for my Core Data model using `Class Definition` as the `Codegen` option.

When I build I get the following output for each of my entities:

```
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: ‘/path/to/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/.Entity+CoreDataClass.swift'
<unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: ‘/path/to/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/Model/.Entity+CoreDataProperties.swift’
...
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

On inspecting the files I can see the following:

Entity+CoreDataClass.swift:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class Entity: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Entity+CoreDataProperties.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import 

extension Entity {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entity> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: “Entity");
    }

    @NSManaged public var title: String?

}
```

In the second, the obvious thing that shouldn’t be there is the empty import statement, which I’m guessing is causing the crash.

Could I be doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

I’ve tried all the usual, clean, clean build folder, restart Xcode/Mac with no luck.

Comment: I am also getting the empty import statement. Seems like a new Apple bug.

Comment: It does seem like the issue should be handled in a better way than it is. Did you see my fix below? It seems like I was doing the wrong thing anyway

Comment: Yes, there is an issue I found: when creating new managed objects and casting them to one of my subclasses, it throws saying it cannot cast. The class name was in a namespace other that the current project's namespace.

Comment: I’m getting this same issue too now I’m building and testing the app. Do you know a workaround?

Comment: I left the `Module` field as the current project and I'm just deleting the empty import statement. I also do not use the code generation yet.

Comment: Yeah, I’ve turned off the feature too and have gone back to good old subclasses. I’ve filed a bug and I’ll update as I know more!

Answer (score 2):

The `Module` field of the entity in the Data Model inspector had a value in it, I deleted this so now it’s empty and the placeholder reads “Global namespace”. This seems to have worked!

Comment: That, and I had to delete `@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item");
    }` that Xcode 8 created. `Item` is the Entity name in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is heavily string-based. Using names such as "Entity" for your entities can lead to unexpected results. Also avoid using names in your data model such as "description", or "item" or "attribute" etc. If you do want to use those names, prefix them: names like "My_entity" or "ACEntity" are fine.